# Как собрать список ссылок на видео Youtube?

Tags: парсер, youtube

Интересует идея/стратегия только)
Собрать небольшое количество ссылок не трудно...

Но как получить например несколько млн ссылок?

Comment: можно наверное воспользоваться API поиска https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Comment: Пробовал. Квоты ограничены(( особо много не напарсишь(((